# Remove Cached UNC URL Credentials Win 10/Server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, share, windows-10

I need to remove the UNC\URL credentials of a share accessed via IP UNC\URL from File Explorer.  For example, last week I logged into 10.10.10.20\someshare, and now, when I go to it, I do not have to put in name and password.  Here are the things I have done that do **not** work:

```
net use (does not display anything)
net use * /d (returns, but no change)
Net use \\10.10.10.20\someshare /d (network connection could not be found)
net use \\10.10.10.20\ipc$ /d (network connection could not be found)
I restarted explorer.exe after those commands
I ran klist purge after those commands
I checked the Credential Manager (nothing)
*update* I checked Stored User Names and Passwords (nothing)
I looked in the registry for the IP (since this lasts through reboots) but there was nothing
```

Even after all those things AND restarting computers, the share comes right up, with no prompts, when typed in File Explorer.  Any ideas?  This makes troubleshooting very difficult.  Also, you cannot log in with different credentials.  Finally, I do not want this behavior, as I have a requirement to have users supply the credentials each time.

Comment: Usually Windows will put saved credentials in the Credential Manager in the Control Panel

Comment: As stated, there are no entries in the Credential Manager.

Comment: Sorry, the notes indicating you had checked the credential manager were in code text box. Do you still get prompted from other workstations that might not have already logged on? What kind of network share is this?

Comment: Yes, if I log in at some other workstation, the first time, taking care NOT to save credentials, I will have to supply credentials.  After that, I go right in.  This is a standard Windows network share, with it's own share name and password - i.e., not AD.  Your question has prompted me to think - what if I made a second share, with different credentials?  I will report back.

Answer (score 1):

This information windows save in registry.

Press Win+R to bring up the **Run** dialog box. Type **regedit** and hit Enter.

For windows 8

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths

For windows server 2012 is more complicated

> [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-***-***-****-500\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths]

Comment: Removing these entries has no effect.  I still go right in, it just doesn't autofill the UNC\URL bar.  The desired objective is to **not** automatically access the share, but to be forced to use name and password each time.

Comment: start-->run--> rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr

Comment: There are no entries in Stored User Names and Passwords.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already removed all instances of saved credentials and you are still able to connect to a share without providing explicit credentials, I believe there are two possibilities:

- Your share is allowing anonymous/guest connections
- You are logged into your workstation with credentials that are valid for the share and Windows is just passing through your credentials automatically. This could be either domain credentials or even local credentials that just happen to have the same username/password as an account on the fileserver.

Comment: The share is not allowing anonymous logins.  I am prompted for passwords from other Win 10 systems (which are then promptly cached, somewhere, on the disk and are never requested again.)  Neither the workstation (Computer)  nor the User objects have been granted permissions to the share.